# How to compare 2 strings with similar characters?

Tags: javascript

The below code is a minimal representation of my problem. What should be done to make the if condition true so that it prints **IP Addresses match!**?

I know there's a problem with encoding of both strings. I am looking for an answer that converts both strings to some uniform encoding that passes the if condition.

```js
var ip1="127.0.0.1";
var ip2="127․0․0․1";  //127%u20240%u20240%u20241
if(ip1 === ip2){
 console.log("IP Addresses match!");
}else{
 console.log("IP Addresses do not match!");
}
```

Comment: why would they not match?

Comment: forgot to use semicolon on var ip2

Comment: `'․' !== '.'`, get rid of that unicode period character.

Comment: @epascarello it looks like there are different characters in the second string. What's that thing where Unicode code points are "collapsed" to deal with things like that? I can never remember, darn it.

Comment: just replace the unicode with dot

Comment: And `console.log(escape(ip1));console.log(escape(ip2));` shows why....

Comment: @All - I know there's a problem with encoding of both strings. I am looking for an answer that converts both strings to same encoding.

Comment: @Beginner it's not a matter of encoding, the unicode code point of those two characters will be different _in any encoding_. You need to _sanitize_ or _validate_ your input and make sure you won't ever get unexpected code points like that for a string that should be purely within the ASCII range.

Comment: [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) is what I was thinking about. In JavaScript it's [String.prototype.normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

Comment: @Pointy `normalize()` will do nothing in this case.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes it will, try `"NFKD"` mode. That converts the "funny" version of the string in the OP to the "good" one. That is, `"127․0․0․1".normalize("NFKD") === "127.0.0.1"`.

Comment: Also, why would you ever want them to be equal? There are infinite unicode characters that might look like a dot, in that case I guess one "solution"  would be to use OCR to make sure that the strings "look the same".

Comment: @Cristy - I need this only for strings containing a dot. I need this because of a limitation in the backend I am using.

Comment: @Beginner Well, why don't you replace the unicode dot with a normal dot in JS before making the comparison? Also, there are many other solutions to this problem, it just is a matter of how general of a solution OP wants.

Comment: For all intents and purposes @Pointy why not post the answer using `normalize("NFKD")`?

Comment: @Cristy - I don't know how to make that replacement. Should I convert ip1 to ip2 or ip2 to ip1? Which is easier and how do I do it?

Comment: If you had `var a = 1X2X` and `var b = 1Y2Y` what replacements should you do to make `a === b` ?

Comment: @Beginner Read **Pointy**'s comment and try `if(ip1.normalize('NFKD') === ip2.normalize('NFKD')){`

Comment: @All - Using `normalize('NFKD')` works. I shall accept it if it's posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments, am posting this answer which uses normalize function in "NFKD" mode.

```js
var ip1="127.0.0.1";
var ip2="127․0․0․1";  //127%u20240%u20240%u20241
if(ip1.normalize("NFKD") === ip2.normalize("NFKD")){
 console.log("IP Addresses match!");
}else{
 console.log("IP Addresses do not match!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace non digit characters with dot.

```js
var ip1 = "127.0.0.1",
    ip2 = "127․0․0․1";
   
ip1 = ip1.replace(/\D+/g, '.');
ip2 = ip2.replace(/\D+/g, '.');

if (ip1 === ip2){
    console.log("IP Addresses match!");
} else {
    console.log("IP Addresses do not match!");
}
```